# ACL does not work properly

Tags: router, cisco-ios, acl

I have a 200.1.1.0/24 network and a web server which is 150.1.1.100. I want to apply an extended ACL to allow devices in network 200.1.1.0/24 with IPs in the range 1-127 to communicate with the WEB server using only HTTP, whereas, the remaining range can only use HTTPS.

I issued below commands but all traffic denied by the router :

```
R1(config-ext-nacl)#permit tcp 200.1.1.0 0.0.0.127 eq www host 150.1.1.100
R1(config-ext-nacl)#permit tcp 200.1.1.128 0.0.0.255 eq 443 host 150.1.1.100
R1(config-if)#ip access-group WEB_ACCESS in
```

I applied ACL (WEB_ACCESS) to inbound interface of the 200.1.1.0 network.
Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: When you show the ACLs, what does it say about hit counts. Also, please edit your question to include the entire configuration (you can obfuscate sensitive information, e.g. passwords).

Comment: Do you want the hosts in the 200.1.1.0 network to reach ONLY the web server, and nothing else?

Comment: @RonTrunk Yes, this is what I want

Comment: Then the answer by @rooster is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
permit tcp 200.1.1.0 0.0.0.127 host 150.1.1.100 eq www
permit tcp 200.1.1.128 0.0.0.127 host 150.1.1.100 eq 443
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was a wildcard mistake. Now, it is working as intended.